# Weak convergence of measures and compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose that we have a sequence of probability measures $\{ \mathbb{P}_n \}$ converging weakly to a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. Suppose that $M$ is a metric space with a compact subset $K$. I would like to show that for any bounded continuous function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$,

> $$ \int_K f \, d\mathbb{P}_n \to \int_K f \, d\mathbb{P}.$$

The main problem here in applying the definition is that $f \mathbf{1}_K$ is not necessarily continuous. I recall that there is a standard result saying that $C_c (M)$ is dense in $L^p(M)$. However, the sequence of approximating functions for $ f \mathbf{1}_K$ clearly depends on the measure space $(M, \mathcal{B} (M), \mathbb{P}_n)$, which is undesirable. How can we prove this?

Comment: You can't prove this, because it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $f=1$, the statement would imply that for each compact subset $K$ of $M$, $\mathbb P_n(K)\to\mathbb P(K)$. There are counter-examples even for $M$ compact (say $[0,1]$ with the usual metric): take $\mathbb P_n:=\delta_{1/n}$.